# dc/crossfilter row chart sorting data that feeds chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dc.js, crossfilter

working from this tutorial [here](http://www.benjaminmbrown.com/2016/02/tutorial-how-to-build-real-time-data-visualization-with-d3-crossfilter-and-websockets-in-python-by-example/comment-page-1/#comment-31983) 
here is my working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HattrickNZ/hcfhds0a/1/)

What I want to do is sort the order of the `spenderRowChart`(graph on right) from top to bottom.

To do this I create a sorted array 
`var topSpender =spendPerName.top(Infinity);`
which if I understand correctly `topSpender` si the same as `spendPerName` but  `topSpender` would be sorted

here is `spendPerName` for ref: 
`spendPerName = nameDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return +d.Spent;});`

And then pass `topSpender` to the `spenderRowChart` here

```
.group(topSpender)
```

But this does not work and I get the following error. [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/HattrickNZ/hcfhds0a/3/)

`Uncaught TypeError: group.all is not a function`

**Can anyone correct the error of my ways?**

More code here

```
   var yearRingChart   = dc.pieChart("#chart-ring-year"),
        spenderRowChart = dc.rowChart("#chart-row-spenders");
    //var connection = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8001/websocket');
    var data1 = [
        {Name: 'Ben', Spent: 330, Year: 2014, 'total':1},
        {Name: 'Aziz', Spent: 1350, Year: 2012, 'total':2},
        {Name: 'Vijay', Spent: 440, Year: 2014, 'total':2},
        {Name: 'Jarrod', Spent: 555, Year: 2015, 'total':1},
    ];
    // set crossfilter with first dataset
    var xfilter = crossfilter(data1),
        yearDim  = xfilter.dimension(function(d) {return +d.Year;}),
        spendDim = xfilter.dimension(function(d) {return Math.floor(d.Spent/10);}),
        nameDim  = xfilter.dimension(function(d) {return d.Name;}),

        spendPerYear = yearDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return +d.Spent;}),
        spendPerName = nameDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return +d.Spent;});

        var topSpender =spendPerName.top(Infinity); //sort top spenders

    function render_plots(){
        yearRingChart
            .width(200).height(200)
            .dimension(yearDim)
            .group(spendPerYear)
            .innerRadius(50);
        spenderRowChart
            .width(250).height(200)
            .dimension(nameDim)
            .group(topSpender)
            .elasticX(true);
        dc.renderAll();
    }
    render_plots();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is my answer, see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HattrickNZ/hcfhds0a/4/)

code: (OPTION A or B worked)

```
spenderRowChart
    .width(250).height(200)
    .dimension(nameDim)
    .group(spendPerName)
    .ordering(function(d) { return -d.value; }) //OPTION A
    .elasticX(true);

//spenderRowChart.ordering(function(d) { return -d.value; }) //OPTION B
```

Similar questions here were helpful:

[Sorting (ordering) the bars in a bar chart by the bar values with dc.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25204782/sorting-ordering-the-bars-in-a-bar-chart-by-the-bar-values-with-dc-js)

[dc.js/crossfilter -> How to sort data in dc.js chart (like row) - Ascending x Descending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21538336/dc-js-crossfilter-how-to-sort-data-in-dc-js-chart-like-row-ascending-x-de)

Answer (score 2):

You need to do `.group(spendPerName)` instead. DC.js works directly on Crossfilter groups. The output of `group.top` (i.e. `topSpender`) is not a group, but a query result in the form of an array of objects.

Comment: tks but think that is more a comment than an answer. I worked it out in the end

Comment: I wrote it from a mobile device, but if I'm not mistaken it is exactly the answer that you arrived at in the end, no?